# How to change background-image css property w/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set the `background-image` css property of say a div using jquery? will something like this work?

```
$("#div").css("backgroundImage", "url('test.jpg')");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[What you have will work](http://jsfiddle.net/S6C5L/), or you can do this:

```
$("#div").css("background-image", "url('test.jpg')");
```

Or [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) takes an object (to set many properties for example):

```
$("#div").css({ backgroundImage: "url('test.jpg')", color: "red" });
```